# Java catch different exceptions

Tags: java

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // write your code here
        try {
            testException(-5);
            testException(11);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("No File Found");
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO Error occurred");
        } finally { //The finally block always executes when the try block exits.
            System.out.println("Releasing resources");
            testException(15);
        }
    }

    public static void testException(int i) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (i < 0) {
            FileNotFoundException myException = new FileNotFoundException();
            throw myException;
        }
        else if (i > 10) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code gives

`No File Found
Releasing resources`

Is it possible to have java catch both IOException as well as FileNotFoundException? It seems to be only able to catch the first exception and doesn't catch the IOException

Comment: It's possible, but not that way. You would have to nest the first try/catch in another try block, and to rethrow the FileNotFoundException from the nested catch block. But why would you do that? Just do the same thing in both catch blocks if that's what you want.

Comment: first "testException(10);" line never execute as per your code

Comment: This is a tricky code example that contains several conditions not as easy to see as it seems. I guess that executing it will show in the standard output an exception not being captured (you should have shown it in your question). See my answer to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The `try` block stops at the first exception thrown, therefore the second call of `testException()` is never executed.

Comment: The second call to testException() is indeed `testException(15);` and it is actually being executed (see my answer which explains it).

Comment: I'm referring to the second one in the `try` block.

Comment: I know, but that call to testException does not throw the IOException anyway (because 10 is not `> 10`). So that is not the problem of Eneres.

Comment: What you say is true but this is also the problem, because even if the second call would satisfy the condition to throw a `FileNotFoundException` it would never be called because of the exception thrown by the first call in the try block.

Comment: It depends on the intention of the programmer. Hopefully he will explain to us :)

Comment: True, we miss a bit of context.

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose your `try/catch/finally` block inside another `try/catch` block because your `finally` block can throw exceptions that must be captured.

Here is how your code works:

- `testException(-5)` throws a `FileNotFoundException`
- `FileNotFoundException`is catched by `catch (FileNotFoundException e)`
- `No File Found` is printed into the standard output
- Then `finally` block is executed (the `testException(10)` sentence is not executed).
- So `Releasing resources` is printed
- And `testException(15)` is executed throwing an `IOException` that is not captured anyway (the program will be interrupted).

If you remove the `throws FileNotFoundException, IOException` from your `main` method the compiler will alert you that an exception is not being captured (the one in the `finally` block).